# How can we intelhide or auto hide or may be even remove the bottom panel in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: panel

This bottom panel is somewhat killing the aesthetics of the desktop.
[image]

The purpose of this panel seems to show which user applications are running right now. Can we remove this panel altogether? If we cannot remove this panel, then the best if we could intelhide or autohide this panel, because a user does not need to see this all the time, just when he takes his mouse to the bottom, it must show up. I right clicked on this panel and nothing shows up to enter its settings. Where we can find its settings.
If someone knows how we can fix this please write. Thanks. :)

Comment: Have you added something to the desktop? That is not a feature of the standard 20.04 installation.

Comment: I searched what to do after installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Google and I followed what looked interesting. Some extra extensions may have been added which does not provide much use as we are now witnessing. I will have to bear the cross for some unwanted installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is provided by the *Window list* GNOME Shell extension.

Ironically, it is not part of the default Ubuntu installation/experience. (In other words, you have probably enabled it some time...)

It does not seem to have an auto-/intellihide option.

You can disable it by opening the Tweaks app, going to the *Extensions* tab, and finding the *Window list* extension in the list.

Comment: I have removed it now. Thank you very much. If we can autohide or intelhide it, then it may have find some use.